# Cosmos DB: Move data from one container to another container in the same database

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

In cosmos db i have two containers

1. Subscriptions
2. UserSubscriptions

I want to move items from **Subscriptions** container to **UserSubscription** container but while moving **Subscriptions** document should convert into UserSubscriptions's document structure.

Is there a way to achive this process?

Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appricated.

Subscriptions json sample:

```
{
    
    "id": "d18e4605-8bac-4bae-95d7-990703033a50",
    "isActive": true,
    "distributionUserIds": [
        "27039a11-9ace-4748-a65e-f463a9e7ef11"
    ],
    "PayerNumber": "0000000005",
    "AccountNumber": "0000000005",
    "_rid": "4XYVAOblmAIBAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/4XYVAA==/colls/4XYVAOblmAI=/docs/4XYVAOblmAIBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-91a9-b9eef09501d6\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1600866120
}
```

UserSubscription json sample:

```
{
    "id": "d18e4605-8bac-4bae-95d7-990703033a50",
    "UUID": "27039a11-9ace-4748-a65e-f463a9e7ef11",
    "Type": "Accounts",
    "Payers": [
        {
            "PayerNumber": "0000000005",
            "Accounts": [
                "0000000005"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "_rid": "C7VEAMxad9UkAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/C7VEAA==/colls/C7VEAMxad9U=/docs/C7VEAMxad9UkAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-2d10-3d41429f01d7\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1617952580
}
```

Comment: have you looked at the migration tool? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#SQLSource

Comment: Aside from the data migration tool, you can also look at changefeed. There's no built-in migration method; you'll need to use one of those tools, or build your own mechanism.

Comment: @silent yes! i have checked the migration tool, but it will not update the json while importing

Answer (score 1):

Yes, migration tool can't updating the json while importing as you said.

There are serval ways to do this:

1. You can use Change Feed to get all documents in **Subscriptions**
   collection and change the document structure by code.
2. You can transform document structure using Data Flow in Azure Data
   Factory.
3. Logic app can also achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to use  data factory for copying:-

1. Create pipe line
2. Create linked services for both cosmos db
3. Define structure
4. Start pipeline  for non duplicate line use pre script
   (sql    to filter) . We can configure more like batch size
5. Setup
   tigger